# Should I install several patches for one version of Unity in their release order?

Tags: unity-game-engine, patch

I am working with Unity 2017.2.0f3 and had a bug in one of my project so I installed the patch 2017.2.0p4 that might have solve it. It is better but still buggy and I read that the patch 2017.2.0p1 could solve this, but I was wondering wether or not I can simply install this second patch, since it is older than the first one. **Do I have to install patches in their release order or doesn't it matter?**

Comment: It does not matter. Each patch is released as a standalone application anyways.

Comment: Okay thanks. So does it mean that the last patch includes the older patches' fixes? I was confused because Unity recommends to install only the patches corresponding to the errors I have, so I first thought that each patch fixes specific stuffs.

Comment: Each patch will contain every bugfix from the previous release(s). Unity recommends this approach because, if you have a game you've been working on since Unity 4.6, there's no telling what might break if you updated to the latest version.

Comment: I usually have multiple Versions (and Patches) of Unity installed parallel, each in separated installation folders on my PC

Comment: Alright thank you it is clear for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

Each patch is released as a standalone application and contains every bugfix from the previous release(s). Like the Unity versions, multiple patches can be installed on one PC in parallel by having each one in a separated installation folder.